# Post request to apple server returns 403 status code

Tags: flutter

[image: I wanted to get token from the server but how to get Candidate.getToken to start work]
I wanted to get token from the server but how get Candidate.getToken to start work

Comment: Do you have `Candidate` method?

Comment: No how can i do that ?

Comment: how you generate the token?

Comment: i tried using sharedPerferences but that dont work i thought Candidate was a Package ,,, how can i get the token from the server help ?

Comment: In _findMyLogin method, what is the json output returned from server? The token?

Comment: it returns 403 status code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242170/discussion-between-zena-addis-and-john-joe).